# How to invert scroll/click direction?

Tags: mobiscroll

Can you tell me how can I invert the direction of the scroll?

For instance, having the mobiscroll in clickpick mode, clicking the bottom arrow should advance in the day/month/year.

For example, the date is 17 10 2012 (dd mm yy). Clicking the arrow below the month, should set it to 11, not 9. Clicking above, would do the opposite: set it to 9.

Is it possible? How?

Thanks. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a problem with the android-ics skin, as it uses arrow symbols instead of +/- symbols.
The following css should fix the problem:

```
.android-ics .dwwbp {
    top: auto;
    bottom: 0;
}
.android-ics .dwwbm {
    top: 0;
    bottom: auto;
}
.android-ics .dwwbm:after {
    border-color: transparent transparent #7e7e7e transparent;
}
.android-ics .dwwbp:after {
    border-color: #7e7e7e transparent transparent transparent;
}
.android-ics .dwwbm.dwb-a:after {
    border-color: transparent transparent #319abd transparent;
}
.android-ics .dwwbp.dwb-a:after {
    border-color: #319abd transparent transparent transparent;
}
```

Comment: Exactly, I was using ICS skin. And that totally solves the problem. Thanks. I would vote you up, but I don't have enough rep. Sorry. Thanks again. :)